Recursive AJAX Call JQuery and SharePoint to get all Items from a SharePoint List
I want to retrieve all items from a SharePoint List. The List has more then 5000 elements, so a recursive ajax call on the REST-API is needed. I can call all the Data into an Array, but the code which calls the Ajax functions don't seem to do anything in the .then() see my code below. I seem to miss the obvious.
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('LISTNAME')/items?$select=ID,Title,TEST,LINK,Modified,Editor/Title&$top=5000&$expand=Editor/Id";

        function getAllItemsFromList(url) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    method: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
                    },
                }).done(function (data) {
                    if (data.d.__next) {
                        console.log("true: ", data.d.results);
                        url = data.d.__next;
                        data.d.results.forEach(element => {
                            all_items_from_list.push(element);
                        });
                        getAllItemsFromList(url);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("false: ", data.d.results);
                        data.d.results.forEach(element => {
                            all_items_from_list.push(element);
                        });
                        //prints all the 7345 Items into the console
                        console.log("false, all_items_from_list: ", all_items_from_list); 
                        resolve("yay");
                    }
                }).fail(function () {
                    console.log("this went horribly wrong!");
                    reject("ERROR!");
                });
            });
        };

        var all_items_from_list = [];

        getAllItemsFromList(url).then(
            function (value) { console.log("I'm here and got following data: ", all_items_from_list) },
            function (error) { /* code if some error */ }
        );

I get the following output:
true: Array(5000) 
false: Array(2346)
false, all_items_from_list: Array(7346)

I found the solution, it was just simple async and await missing... somtimes a little bit of fresh air helps.
 async function getAllItemsFromList(url) {
            await $.ajax({
                url: url,
                method: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
                },
            }).done(function (data) {
                if (data.d.__next) {
                    url = data.d.__next;
                    data.d.results.forEach(element => {
                        all_items_from_list.push(element);
                    });
                    getAllItemsFromList(url);
                } else {
                    data.d.results.forEach(element => {
                        all_items_from_list.push(element);
                    });
                }
            }).fail(function () {
                console.log("Es konnten nicht alle Daten abgerufen werden!");
            });
        };
```

